# OfficeConverter issue when deploying to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, openxml

I have a web API which simply

- clone a .docx file
- convert that cloned .docx to a .pdf format

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;


[HttpPost("clone")]
public IActionResult CloneBillFromTemplate()
{
     var templateFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Bill", "PaymentTempl.docx");
     var clonedFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Bill", "ClonedBill.docx");
     var pdfFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Bill", "FinalBill.pdf");
     
     using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateFilePath, true))
     {
         var clonedDoc = wordDoc.Clone(clonedFilePath);
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
         clonedDoc.Save();
         clonedDoc.Close();
     }

     using (var converter = new OfficeConverter.Converter())
     {
         converter.Convert(clonedFilePath, pdfFilePath);
     }

     return Ok();
}
```

Everything works fine when debugging (for sure :3) and also on IIS

But when I deploy to Azure App service, I got this type of error (stack trace + exception message).

> Could not read registry to check Word version

> Could not find registry key Word.Application\CurVer
> at OfficeConverter.Word..ctor()
> at OfficeConverter.Converter.get_Word()
> at OfficeConverter.Converter.Convert(String inputFile, String outputFile, Stream logStream) at ....

Could you guys help me on this? Thanks all!!!

***feel free to ask for more information you need to detect this issue*

**Update**
Looks like this is the issue with the pdf converter pacakge I'm using, not the OpenXML

Comment: can you paste the whole stack trace message

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi, just updated the question including the stack trace

Comment: well, I think this issue not on the open xml but rather than other pacakge I used to convert to pdf file though

Answer (score 1):

It seems your application is relying on the Windows registry in a way that is not supported. If you are running on a Linux App Service, that would be the first thing to swap out, though my guess is that you are already running on Windows.

> Apps have read-only access to much (though not all) of the registry of the virtual machine they are running on. In practice, this means registry keys that allow read-only access to the local Users group are accessible by apps. One area of the registry that is currently not supported for either read or write access is the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive.
>
> Write-access to the registry is blocked, including access to any per-user registry keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#registry-access

If you can't refactor your code to not rely on such dependencies, I would suggest you put your application inside a [Windows docker container](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/app-service-announces-general-availability-of-windows-container-support/). If you can run that locally, it should run on App Service as well.